# HTTP request differences between Java API/Google Chrome requests?

Tags: java, http, google-chrome, get, request

Whoever is on the side of the webserver: how do they differentiate (as in, what especifically is different) between a HTTP request made through the Google Chrome browser (page refresh with no forms or nothing, a GET supposedly right?), and an HTTP request made through the JavaAPI:

Using the following libs:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

By doing the following:

```
String MY_URL = "www.mysite.com";
URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying the device requesting a response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151756/identifying-the-device-requesting-a-response)

Comment: I want to confirm that the User Agent is the ONLY thing that changes, and to know what are the exact differences between them. If it's only the User Agent, I want to know the one that Java requests. Had already gone through that link and not gotten to where I wanted. @BrianRoach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a network sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see the request headers from Chrome and from your code.  Or you can use [Chrome's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#http_headers) which shows the request headers also.

They will be different in many ways.  Exactly which ways depends on many things, like the version of Chrome, and the OS being used.

Which differences matter depends on exactly which web server you are using, so we cannot really determine that for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really worried to know user's Browser Info then you need to determine the Browser and pass that to action..

Look at [Navigator `appName` Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_appname.asp)